# Reversing Naive Bayes to find extreme points of data sets

Tags: naive-bayes-classifier, bayesian-networks

I'd like to know if this is a sensible idea and if there exist any already formed methods to do this (I'm new to the data science area).

Essentially, I have used Naive Bayes to accurately classify three types of food, based on their nutritious value (fat, salt, sugar, protein, and carbohydrates as my features).

Now that I can accurately classify these foods, Is there a method which uses the Naive Bayes to reverse this approach, and find the extreme values these features can be to be still classified as a type of food?

E.g: The max fat food1 can be, to still be considered food1.

I realize that these values will change, as other nutrient variables are changed, but I wondered if an optimized set of equations could be obtained in 5 dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "decision boundary", which is the set of (extreme) points laying on the boundary between classes.

[image]

Decision boundary of NB is a set of points $\boldsymbol{x}$ that satisfy at least one of these  $K(K-1)/2$ conditions $$i\neq j \in [1, K]:{\Bbb P}(\boldsymbol{x}, C_i)={\Bbb P}(\boldsymbol{x}, C_j) \overset{\forall k}{\geq} {\Bbb P}(\boldsymbol{x}, C_k)$$
Generally, Naive Bayes does not learn an explicit decision boundary (specially when categorical features are involved), however, for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/142215/195246) is the derivation of NB boundary for *continuous* variables when ${\Bbb P}(\boldsymbol{x}|C_i)$ is chosen from exponential family (e.g. a Gaussian). Nonetheless, you could still select a set of random points, then assign a class to each, and finally plot them using something like t-SNE to get a sense of decision boundaries. For example, a tool like [this interactive t-SNE plot](https://github.com/plotly/dash-tsne) would be helpful:

[image: t-SNE explorer]

Or a library like [mlxtend.plotting](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/plotting/plot_decision_regions/) that carries out a similar procedure:

[image]

On the contrary, models like multi-class logistic regression and SVM both have explicit decision boundaries, which are equations of learned parameters $\boldsymbol{w}$ such as $$w_0+w_1\text{fat}+w_2\text{salt}+w_3\text{sugar}=0$$ that you can access via common libraries.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much